# Python group by find duplicate addresses

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby

Hello  i have a dataframe where i have the columns **Date , IP address** and **Username**.
I want to group by the dataframe in order to find the IP addresses which have mulitple users.
I want something like :
IP Address  Username
sample1     user1
user2
sample2     user3
user4

I am using the code:

```
group=dict(df.groupby(by=['IP address','Date'])['Username'].count())
ips=list()
for k,v in group.items():
    if v>=2:
        ips.append(k)
ip_address=list()
for x  in ips:
    ip_address.append(x[0])
ip_address
ips=log_cumulative2[log_cumulative2['IP address'].isin(ip_address)]
```

When i export the df into a spreadsheet i also get IPS with just one user.Any help?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is using `agg` method. In this method you can pass a dictionary indicating what should be done for each column. With `agg` method you can use multiple aggregation methods for each column:

```
result = df.groupby(['IP address','Date']).agg({
    'Username':['count',list],
    'ips':list })
# removing the unique ones
result = result[result['Username','count'] >=2]
```

This code creates a dataframe that has count of each unique pair of `IP address` and `Date` as its index. Then it has a list of `Usernames`. you can use `set` function if you want to remove the duplicated `Usernames`.
It also has a list of `ips`.

Comment: That is actually great , but is there a way to select those with count larger or equal to 2?In order to find ips with more than 2 users.

Comment: you can filter the count of Username. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @GeorgePapadopoulos just make sure that you are using the correct column index. Since it will generate multi level column index, it might be a bit different to what you are used to.